# How do you add a link in the description of one section of the customizer to another section in a different panel?

Tags: theme-customizer

I want to add a link like the one that currently exists in the Menu Locations sections of the customizer that says "You can also place menus in widget areas with the Custom Menu widget." The "widget areas" text link automatically opens the Widget panel without refreshing the whole page. How can I duplicate that functionality for whatever section?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: customizer link to widget area]

Comment: can you show the image what you need exactly?

Comment: Added a screenshot above. I want a link like that, to a different section but working the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant line that generates that link in `wp-includes\class-wp-customize-nav-menus.php` is

```
$description .= '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'You can also place menus in <a href="%s">widget areas</a> with the &#8220;Custom Menu&#8221; widget.' ), "javascript:wp.customize.panel( 'widgets' ).focus();" ) . '</p>';
```

and the more relevant part of it 
`javascript:wp.customize.panel( 'widgets' ).focus();" )`

so it seems like the key for having this kind of functionality is to know the name of the panel... now for sections there is no explicit example in core but might be worth trying to use `javascript:wp.customize.section( 'your section name' ).focus();` as the href of the link